# Nilpotency of BG^+

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have become interested in knowing if there are conditions, in the literature, under which the action of the fundamental group of BG^+ acts nilpotently on its higher homotopy groups, where the + denotes the Quillen +-construction. In other words, when is BG^+ a nilpotent space? How does the Quillen +-construction affect nilpotency?

Could anyone please refer me to a place in the literature or provide an analysis?

Thank you.

Comment: You should bear in mind the Kan-Thurston theorem: for any connected space $X$ there exists a group $G$ and a perfect subgroup $P$ such that $BG^+_P=X$.

Comment: @Neil: I am primarily interested in the case that G is the infinite symmetric group.